# List maven dependencies in Java / Scala

Tags: java, scala, maven, dependency-management

I want to expose the list of maven dependency artifacts (with version) over an HTTP endpoint. This [blogpost](https://grep.codeconsult.ch/2010/07/08/list-all-your-maven-dependencies/) solves my problem but unfortunately it's in `bash` and not Java/Scala.

```
mvn -o dependency:list \
| grep ":.*:.*:.*" \
| cut -d] -f2- \
| sed 's/:[a-z]*$//g' \
| sort -u
```

Output

```
com.amazonaws:amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib:jar:1.0.0
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-acm:jar:1.10.64
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-api-gateway:jar:1.10.64
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-autoscaling:jar:1.10.64
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.10.64
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudfront:jar:1.10.64
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudhsm:jar:1.10.64
com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch:jar:1.10.64
```

Can someone share some pointers on how to achieve this in code?

Comment: Easiest would probably be to run that command to create a file, then just serve up that file as a static asset.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a maven task to print the dependencies to a resource directory at the time of compilation.

An alternative is that you can inspect the [classpath](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/) of the `ClassLoader`, get the jars and work it out using the artifacts but that's much, much more fragile.